# How to listen to an event and a timer at the same time in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When the page is loaded, a timer with a random limit starts. I want to trigger some actions when **the timer has run out and the user has pressed a button.**

**Update: Only when both two conditions are satisfied will the action start.**

**Update 2: To be clear, if 'button clicked' is event A, 'timer goes out' is event B, then the condition is A *and* B, not A *or* B, that's a little bit counter-intuitive.
(ps: release the click won't cancel event A)**

```
const timeupEvent = new Event("timeup");

function f() {
    document.dispatchEvent(timeupEvent);
}

setTimeout(f, limit);

button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.addEventListener('timeup', action);
})
```

My code is shown as above. When the user clicks before the timer goes out, it runs smoothly, but when he clicks after that, the code can't run correctly.

I Believe that's because `document.addEventListener('timeup', action)` won't be triggered if the event is emitted before the execution of the code, but I don't have proper solutions for it.

Thanks for your help and advice!

Comment: To be clear, if the user clicked the button before the timer ran out, released it, then the timer ran out - you'd want the event to be dispatched. Am I correct?

Comment: Better to add setInterval and clearInterval in JS

Comment: @Botan As long as the button has been clicked (no matter it's released or not), and the timer ran out. Sorry again for the misunderstanding. You can check my update. I think Joaquin has offered a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you actually need the timeup event you could simple check how much time has elapsed:

```
const pageLoadAt = Date.now();
const limit = 5000; // ms

button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (Date.now() - pageLoadAt >= limit) {
        action();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a really nice approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if the user clicks before timer runs out, the action won't be triggered, which isn't correct. I've updated my original post. Sorry if it causes some misunderstandings.

Comment: @DavidGuo your update says "Only when both two conditions are satisfied will the action start". Is it possible that you want an *or* not *and*? So the action should always be called, either by pressing a button or the timer running out. You need to state your requirements clearly.

Comment: @timotgl Sorry for the misunderstanding again. I think Joaquin has offered a good solution.

Comment: @DavidGuo I've read your "update 2" and I still don't get it. You're contradicting yourself in your first comment to this answer. "if the user clicks before timer runs out, the action won't be triggered, which isn't correct" - why wouldn't it be correct if both conditions need to be satisfied?

Comment: @timotgl Sorry for the late reply, let me explain a little bit. I actually mean that in your code, if the usr clicks before timer runs out, the action won't be triggered, **even after the timer runs out sometime in the future.** It indeed acts correctly at the time the user clicks the button, but it doesn't perform correctly in the future.

Comment: @timotgl To solve that, you need a variable to track the status of the timer (whether it has run out or not)

Comment: @timotgl although I've stated that 'release the click won't cancel event A', but in actual running, the `EventListener` function only runs once.

Comment: @DavidGuo After reading your comment just now I've understood what you're actually trying to do. This is still not clear at all from reading your original question. The missing word you're looking for is "schedule". You want to schedule the action to run in the future if the two events both have happened in the past.